# duvida com entity e limit

Tags: entity-framework, select-limit

preciso buscar os ultimos 100 registros do banco, estou usando o codigo a seguir, porem ele retorna os 100 primeiros:

```
 dynamic data = null;
        try
        {
            data = limit == 0 ?
                (from p in contexto.Set<TEntity>() select p).Where(predicate).ToList() :
                (from p in contexto.Set<TEntity>() select p).Where(predicate).ToList().Take(limit);

        }
```

tentei colocar o .Last(), mas deu um erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como posso resolver isso ?

Answer (score 0):

**Erro:**

Está acontecendo um erro de conversão `List<TEntity>` para `TEntity`, eles são diferentes e a conversão é necessária. O `Last()` retorna o **último elemento da lista**, e na verdade precisa dos **100 últimos elementos**, viu a diferença?

**Fato:**

Estou buscando os 100 últimos registros do Banco (`ORDER BY CAMPO DESC`)

**Então:**

Ordena a sua SQL pelo campo chave ([OrderByDescending](https://www.dotnetperls.com/orderbydescending)) traga os **100 primeiros registros** que na verdade **são os 100 últimos registro**.

```
var lista = (from p in contexto.Set<TEntity>() select p)
             .Where(predicate)
             .OrderByDescending(orderByPredicate)
             .Take(limit)
             .ToList();
```

***Observação:*** quando colocou `ToList()` e depois `Take(100)` trouxe todos os registros e depois pegou 100, ***isso é um grande erro***, faça a `SQL` trazer somente os ***100 registros***, como demonstrado no exemplo.

Depois disso se precisar fazer a **Ordernação** no `List` de `Objeto`, como já trouxe os ***100 últimos registro*** e está na memória faça assim (qualquer filtro, ordernação, etc.):

```
lista.OrderBy(predicate);
```